Client Application throws IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager throws an exception
When I try to connect to WebSphere MQ Server using C# Application, I encounter the exception: "The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception." I have added reference the MQ DLL, amqmdnet.dll in the C# Client application to communicate with the MQ server, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I might have missed on the client side that could prevent communication? Please advise.
Thanks
When i communicate to MQ server and supposed to get MQ Connection is Successful but i got Exception

It would help if you can post your code? From the exception details, it appears that your application is trying to connect to queue manager in unmanaged mode that requires the  MQ C client libraries as well.

referenced amqmdnet.dll in my client application. Do i need to install IBM MQ Web Sphere Client to connect?

We will need to look at your code to help you.
